# Why do I get an exception "Invalid algorithm specified" in CEnroll2Class?

Tags: c#, cryptography, windows-xp, com-interop

I want to implement CSR generation in C# for Windows XP SP3.

Added by assembly *Interop.XENROLLLib*

CSR Generation Code:

```
private string GenerateObsolete(string subject)
{
    var certEnroll = new CEnroll2Class();

    certEnroll.ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)";
    certEnroll.ProviderType = 24;

    certEnroll.ContainerName = $"FGR-{Guid.NewGuid()}";

    certEnroll.HashAlgorithm = "SHA-256";
    //certEnroll.HashAlgID = 32780;
    certEnroll.KeySpec = 1;
    certEnroll.GenKeyFlags = 1;

    return certEnroll.createRequest(XECR_CMC, subject, null);
}
```

If the **HashAlgorithm** property is not set, then the request is successfully generated and by default I get the **SHA1** signature algorithm. But when setting any other algorithm, I get the exception:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090008): Invalid algorithm specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090008)
   at XENROLLLib.CEnroll2Class.set_HashAlgorithm(String pbstr)"
```

I tested on two machines with **Windows XP SP3**. I also tried to specify **HashAlgI** instead of the algorithm name.

Here is a list of supported algorithms.
[image]

Please, any tips from you.